# Quorum private transaction not working - Every function returns undefined

Tags: quorum, private-transaction

I am following the quickstart tuto on Quorum website.

I launched the examlple script, which is showing how to manage private transactions. In the example, there are 3 members A, B, C. The script creates a private smart contract between members A and C. Then, the script SET a value in the smart contract, and GET the value, requesting it with respectively member A, B and C. Members A and C can GET the value and member B see "undefined".

I copy pasted the contract, and added a function from mine.

I launch again the script and then I get "undefined" with all three members A, B and C.

This blows my mind, each time I try to add functions in this contract (regenerating binary and abi), I get "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Any news?

This is the output of the example private_transaction script:

Creating contract...
Waiting for transaction to be mined ...
Getting contractAddress from txHash:  {
blockHash: '0x1e6eeb059776beb32a437b8722ae38d7f31694f89218adcac05b1e0149246b2d',
blockNumber: 870,
contractAddress: '0xC846E039BC5c0b98273066bC72cf70FFb97b2a82',
cumulativeGasUsed: 0,
from: '0x1027a1df820ba518a3948435ef2b9625a695caa4',
gasUsed: 0,
isPrivacyMarkerTransaction: false,
logs: [],
logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
status: false,
to: null,
transactionHash: '0xd8cbeb3c9b6ba0fabf02c962014a4c8907023266f5fb8d1d99be518ed2dbf38d',
transactionIndex: 0,
type: '0x0'
}
Address of transaction:  0xC846E039BC5c0b98273066bC72cf70FFb97b2a82
Use the smart contracts 'get' function to read the contract's constructor initialized value ..
Member1 obtained value at deployed contract is: undefined
Use the smart contracts 'set' function to update that value to 123 .. - from member1 to member3
Verify the private transaction is private by reading the value from all three members ..
Member1 obtained value at deployed contract is: undefined
Member2 obtained value at deployed contract is: undefined
Member3 obtained value at deployed contract is: undefined